# .colors function in barChart dc.js with only two options

Tags: colors, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js

I want to create a color function which shows red when the value is negative and green otherwise in a barChart.

Here is what I've come up with so far :

```
var colorChoice = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["positive","negative"])
                                    .range(["#00FF00","#FF0000"]);
hitsPerDaybarChart
.colors(function(d) {return(colorChoice((d.hits>0) ? "positive":"negative"));})
```

But I get the following error message : `TypeError: Object function (d) {return(colorChoice((d.pnl>0) ? "positive":"negative"));} has no method 'range'`.

All help welcome. Thanks.

Comment: `hitsPerDaybarChart.colors(function(d) {return d.hits>0 ? colorChoice("positive") : colorChoice("negative");})`?

Comment: I see that you are doing the same, actually...my bad. I created a simpler example mocking appending a rectangle and filling its color and it worked...so, it is definitely not in this last statement.

Comment: And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yxAF/), FWIW.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Thanks for trying it out but the issue seems to lie in the dc.js interpretation of the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to use the [`colorAccessor`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colorAccessor__anchor) function.

1) Define your color range and domain:

```js
.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["positive", "negative"])
                          .range(["#00FF00", "#FF0000"]))
```

2) Define your color accessor:

```js
.colorAccessor(function(d) {
  if (d.value > 0) {
    return "positive";
  }
  return "negative";
})
```

Hopefully this JSFiddle helps: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/9ELWV/

---

Note: with the latest versions of d3.js, use `d3.scaleOrdinal()` instead of `d3.scale.ordinal()`.

Comment: I updated your answer to mention that with the latest versions of d3, it's "scaleOrdinal" instead of "scale.ordinal". I hope that's ok :). Also, thanks, I was going crazy trying to make the colorAccessor work!